# How to schedule local-notifications when the app in background for iOS in Nativescript -angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hai am developing an ios application using Nativescript-angular framework.My app contains local notifications functionality using timer. but I click the home button In my phone the timer was destroyed and notifications not came. Is there anyway to run the timer when my app is in background?

Comment: Use [BackgroundExecution](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution) / [BackgroundTask](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution).

Comment: is there anyway to know when my app goes into background in nativeascript?

Comment: Yes, all you had to do was read steps from above links.

Comment: Ok I have a small doubt..How to access the custom delegate to my component classes?

Comment: You are not suppose to, none of the UI updates will work until app resumes. You can still trigger notifications, hit APIs etc., You may update your component on resume.

Answer (score 0):

In order show notifications after app is moved to background, you should use [BackgroundTask](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ios-background-execution).

If you like to perform any operation even when the app is not running, then you should opt for [BackgroundFetch](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/BackgroundExecution#long-running-tasks)